# Set up Chrome OS Vanilla without internet in Windows 7 via USB

Tags: internet, google-chrome-os

I had downloaded Chrome OS Vanilla and wrote it on my USB stick in my Windows 7. After booting from it, the setup screen appears. I cannot continue from there since there is no internet connection. I am using a USB dongle (EVDO) to connect to the internet in Windows 7.

Does it work in Chrome OS? 
How can I set up the OS without internet?

Comment: Please do not **make everything bold**. That makes your posts harder to read than without it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I had downloaded Chrome OS Vanilla

From where, exactly?  I believe this is important to know.  I mean, did you use the [Chromium OS](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os)?  One of the [Hexxah builds](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) (probably since you state Vanilla)?  Did you visit [the page hosted on a Google Server that provides you a link to a site off their server, that directs you to something similar to the OS they use on their product?](https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoslinux/)?  I mean that's probably the best suggestion right there, since... you know... it is Google's Operating System.

> I am using a USB dongle - EVDO

Remember how you had to install the drivers and software in Windows 7 in order to use this... before you could use this?  How exactly did you install the drivers and software for it with the Chrome OS?

> Does it work in Chrome OS?

Does what work... that unknown and unnamed USB dongle?  [EVDO is a communications standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution-Data_Optimized), not a brand or model name.  That makes it a bit more difficult to see if there are known issues building a version of Chrome OS with that software already in it.  In general though, I wouldn't expect that it could work with your dongle.  CrOS Linux is a specific version of Linux that the people at Google have been working on, to work with some specific hardware.  Chromium OS is a more generalized version of this that some motivated individuals have been working on to work on a wider scope of hardware.  However, they cannot plan for every hardware combination.  They expect you to have a network card or wireless network card and the OS includes generic drivers for such.  It isn't even compatible with as wide a range of network interfaces as you will find in other versions of Linux.

Here is what you do.

You look to see if there are any Linux drivers and software for your USB EVDO dongle there.  You [contact Hexxah](http://blog.hexxeh.net/contact) (if that's the version you downloaded) and see if he can help you get **HIS** build of CrOS to work with those drivers.

Comment: Actually CROS linux isn't directly from google - see the bottom "Cr OS Linux is not related to Google. The service is powered by SUSE Studio." - It seems to be a suse varient that runs cinnamon.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes.  My mistake.  It is the version that Google themselves directs you to use.  It is the version that when you are on a page hosted by Google, that Google has created a link to.  I shall edit the answer accordingly.  It may not be related to Google, but it is obviously recommended by them.

Comment: Chrome OS Vanilla from http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/ BSNL EVDO U500 DATA CARD and it is windows 7  and **I have a new trouble. Please go to http://superuser.com/questions/585577/important-disk-pen-drive-cleaned-using-command-prompt-not-able-to-use-pen-dr**