# Not able to use pen drive after cleaning it using command prompt

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, google-chrome-os

I had downloaded [Chrome OS Vanilla](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) and wrote it to an 8 GB pen drive. After I checked it out I tried to remove it.

I plugged in my pen drive and it asked me to format it. There was only one option of 1 GB. After formatting I just had 1GB on my pen drive.

Then I [followed this procedure](http://erlern.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/repair-unallocated-space-from-usb-flash-drive/):

- Run » CommandPrompt
- Type `diskpart` » <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type `list disk` » <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Find out the allocated number of your disk
- Type `select disk X` » <kbd>Enter</kbd> (X is the number for your drive)
- Type `clean` » <kbd>Enter</kbd>

After following this when I plug in my device it asks me to format disk. It shows unknown capacity.

After clicking start it says *Windows was unable to complete the format*. Then when I close it, it says:

> Windows can't format H. Check to see that the disk and drive are connected properly, make sure that the disk is not read-only, and then try again. For more information, search Help for read-only files and how to change them.

Now I cannot use it and it has no memory.

In disk management, I had right clicked and clicked create new simple volume. Then I got my 8 GB back but in RAW format and it was write protected. The next day, when I plugged in my USB it was write protected and disk management shows Unallocated.(now)

After typing clean and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in command prompt I get:

> DiskPart has encountered an error: Incorrect function. See the System
> Event Log for more information.

When I double click the device in Computer:

> I:\ is not accessible.
>
> The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure
> that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume
> is not corrupted.

When I run HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool, V2.1.8 and click format I get:

> Device media is write protected

Comment: Please don't use that much formatting. Thanks.

Comment: THIS QUESTION DID NOT GET AN ANSWER. So I have the right to ask

Comment: @chndn Try [BOOTICE](http://www.pendriveapps.com/bootice-partition-flash-drive-edit-boot-sector/), run the tool, select your usb drive, then parts manage and finally reformat it keeping a single partition.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to put it in another computer if possible, if that still doesn't work then you probably have a bad flash drive.

You can go into disk management (Right click on my computer and click manage, then click on disk management) see if it recognizes your drive, you can try uninstalling it from device manager as well, though it may be tough to find.

Swap it around USB ports.

If none of that works then there isn't much that I know of that you can do.

Comment: I created  a new simple volume and it asked me to format it. But it says **the disk is write protected**

Comment: HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool says there is no media in the specified device

Answer (score 0):

If you have another 8gb drive, format it, image it with Win32DiskImager, and then write the image to the bad drive.

If it's still nothing, then the drive is bad.

Comment: I dont have another. Should I need the same Jetflash Transcend 8GB 8.07?

Comment: I GOT IT. I HAD TO PLUG INTO ANOTHER USB PORT (IT DOESNT WORK N OTHER TWO) AN DUSE THE TOOL IN http://erlern.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/repair-unallocated-space-from-usb-flash-drive/  THANKS